# Lamps not casting any light

Tags: rendering, light

(On blender render, not cycles) I turned off ambient occlusion to get a faster render for a while and I just realized my lamps don't work, Hemi, Spot, Sun, Area, Point... None of them cast any light, the scene is just completely black, I don't know what's going on! Help.

Comment: Are your lights on the same layer and are they render restricted in the outliner?

Comment: Is it possible you could upload your .blend?

Comment: There are multiple reasons why you are experiencing this , but without a picture of your scene settings or more info on the file in question is very hard to guess.

Comment: maybe he went blind :O!